# Stuck using pandas to build RPG item generator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, generator

I am trying to build a simple random item generator for a game I am working on.
So far I am stuck trying to figure out how to store and access all of the data. I went with pandas using .csv files to store the data sets.

I want to add weighted probabilities to what items are generated so I tried to read the csv files and compile each list into a new set.

I got the program to pick a random set but got stuck when trying to pull a random row from that set.

I am getting an error when I use .sample() to pull the item row which makes me think I don't understand how pandas works. I think I need to be creating new lists so I can later index and access the various statistics of the items once one is selected.

Once I pull the item I was intending on adding effects that would change the damage and armor and such displayed. So I was thinking of having the new item be its own list then use damage = item[2] + 3 or whatever I need

error is: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sample'

Can anyone help with this problem? Maybe there is a better way to set up the data?

here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import random 

df = [pd.read_csv('weapons.csv'), pd.read_csv('armor.csv'), pd.read_csv('aether_infused.csv')]

def get_item():
    item_class = [random.choices(df, weights=(45,40,15), k=1)] #this part seemed to work. When I printed item_class it printed one of the entire lists at the correct odds
    item = item_class.sample()
    print (item) #to see if the program is working
get_item()
```

Comment: I am wondering if the read_csv function is not what is needed here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting slightly confused with lists vs list elements. This should work. I stubbed your dfs with simple ones

```
import pandas as pd
import random 

# Actual data. Comment it out if you do not have the csv files 
df = [pd.read_csv('weapons.csv'), pd.read_csv('armor.csv'), pd.read_csv('aether_infused.csv')]

# My stubs -- uncomment and use this instead of the line above if you want to run this specific example
# df = [pd.DataFrame({'weapons' : ['w1','w2']}), pd.DataFrame({'armor' : ['a1','a2', 'a3']}), pd.DataFrame({'aether' : ['e1','e2', 'e3', 'e4']})]

def get_item():
    # I removed [] from the line below -- choices() already returns a list of length 1
    item_class = random.choices(df, weights=(45,40,15), k=1) 

    # I added [0] to choose the first element of item_class which is a list of length 1 from the line above
    item = item_class[0].sample()
    print (item) #to see if the program is working
get_item()
```

prints random rows from random dataframes that I setup such as

```
  weapons
1      w2
```

Comment: Hmm... would I be able to use my weapons and armor and aether data sets in this method? I am trying to avoid having to enter hundreds of items into each list

Comment: @KevinMcGreal   I do not understand your question. You have your dataframes in your csvs right? I coded them up as an example because I do not have your csvs but you load them up in your question. so you should replace my `df = ...` line with tyours `df = ...` line from your question

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I am still only a couple months into learning python and don't know what to call everything. Where would I insert my csv files in this code?

Comment: Not a problem! all been there. I edited my answer so it should work with your actual data. If you want to see that it works with my sample data, follow the 'comment this uncomment that' instructions in the code

Comment: Its working! So now I am trying to figure out how to, for example, pull Damage from an item so I can display it on a GUI and add to it if necessary after adding effects. I tried print (item[3]) to see if it would display a value but got a KeyError

Comment: Glad this part is working! Consider accepting the answer per the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and if you have more questions, keep asking! As for `item[3]`, `item` here is pandas DataFrame so you may want to brush up on how to access specific cells a dataframe